# DMS ignore empty tables

Tags: aws-dms, aws-documentdb

I am trying to migrate data from Documentdb(source) to Rds(target) through DMS. They are 4 tables in source which are empty and migration task is processing with error state. The requirement is that these 4 tables will be filled with data in 2 weeks. I need to ignore these tables and make the migration status to be successful. I am not sure how can we ignore these errors for 2 weeks and make them available later. Is there any thing to change in task setting json file which can ignore these tables for time being.
"ErrorBehavior": {
"DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"EventErrorPolicy": "IGNORE",
"DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
"DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
"TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
"TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
"TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
"RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
"RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
"RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
"RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
"RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
"ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
"ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
"ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
"ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
"FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
"FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
"FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false
},

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can we ignore specific tables in source during migration through DMS??

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the migration task, in the *Table mappings* section specify selection rules and exclude each empty table, something like this:
[image]